# How to order by from third table (related to Max(), join)

Tags: mysql

Let me explain the question with the following example: (long but easy to understand)

This is how my MySQL database looks like:

table name: `general_info`

```
Movie_ID    movie_title
1           Iron Man
2           Superman
3           Batman
```

table name: `cast`

```
Movie_ID     Cast_Name              
1            Robert Downey Jr.      
1            Gwyneth Paltrow        

2            Henry Cavill           
2            Amy Adams              

3            Christian Bale         
3            Heath Ledger
```

Table name `production_companies`

```
Movie_ID       Production_name        
1              Marvel                 
1              Paramount              

2              Legendary Pictures     
2              DC Entertainment       

3              Snycopy
```

table name `user_cast_preference`

```
user_id     user_cast_name         user_cast_rating
1           Robert Downey Jr.      95
1           Gwyneth Paltrow        45 
1           Christian Bale         80
1           Heath Ledger           90
```

table name `user_production_preference`

```
user_id        user_production_name   user_production_rating
1              Marvel                 85
1              Paraamount             70
1              Syncopy                65
```

---

---

Now, I am able to fetch all movies that are in user's preferred cast + preferred production company, using this query

```
select general_info.movie_id,movie_title from general_info

inner join cast on general_info.movie_id = cast.movie_id 
inner join production_companies on general_info.movie_id = production_companies.movie_id

where cast.cast_name in (select user_cast_name from user_cast_preference) 
or production_companies.production_companie_name in (select user_production_name from user_production_preference)

group by movie_title
```

**Current Result:**

```
movie_id     moive_title

3            Batman
1            Iron Man
```

Only batman and Ironman got fetched because at least one of the actor or production company was involved in it (which is also in user's preferred list)

Till now everything is just fine. But I want to do this:

I want to order movies by this algorithem.

I will compare all fetched movies with the given rating in my tables and order them by Top to bottom.

In my case, let's compare Batman and Iron Man.

This is how, I decided to compare.

```
Take the top rated cast from Ironman + Top rated production company from iron man

Take the top rated cast from Batman + Top rated production company from batman
```

that is:

```
95 (iron man) + 85 (marvel) = 180
90 (heath ledger) + 65 (syncopy) = 155
```

Now Iron man has more rating than Batman, so **expected result** will be:

```
movie_id     moive_title    total_rating

1            Iron Man       180
3            BatMan         155
```

I hope, I made myself clear.

Comment: On a sidenote: The datamodel and table names could be better. Somehow along the lines of `movie(movie_id, name)`, `actor(actor_id, name)`, `movie_actor(movie_id, actor_id)`, `company(company_id, name)`, `movie_company(movie_id, company_id)`, `user(user_id, name)`, `user_preference_actor(user_id, actor_id, rating)`, `user_preference_company(user_id, company_id, rating)`.

Comment: In your sample data there is just one user and you don't limit your query to one user, but you say "Now, I am able to fetch all movies that are in user's preferred cast", so I thought this is all about a user's preferences. Is it or did you mean "**users'** preferences" instead of "**user's** preferences"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all movies where the user either have an actor or a company (or both) in their preferences. Then you want to sort by the sum of top preferences.

I'd look up the maximum points of user-rated casts and maximum points of user-rated companies per movie first and then outer join these aggregation results to the movie table:

```
select gi.*
from general_info
left join
(
  select c.movie_id, max(ucp.user_cast_rating) as points
  from cast c
  join user_cast_preference ucp on ucp.user_cast_name = c.cast_name
  where ucp.user_id = 1
  group by c.movie_id
) p1 on p1.movie_id = gi.movie_id
left join
(
  select pc.movie_id, max(upp.user_cast_rating) as points
  from production_companies pc
  join user_production_preference upp on upp.user_cast_name = pc.cast_name
  where upp.user_id = 1
  group by pc.movie_id
) p2 on p1.movie_id = gi.movie_id
where p1.points > 0 or p2.points > 0
order by coalesce(p1.points, 0) + coalesce(p2.points, 0) desc;
```

Comment: Perfect, flexible and amazing. Sorry for not choosing it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are getting "production_companies.production_companie_name" in your original code

```
SELECT general_info.Movie_ID,
       general_info.movie_title,
       MAX(user_cast_preference.user_cast_rating + user_production_preference.user_production_rating) AS total_rating
FROM ((((general_info
         INNER JOIN CAST ON general_info.Movie_ID = cast.Movie_ID)
        INNER JOIN production_companies ON cast.Movie_ID = production_companies.Movie_ID)
       INNER JOIN user_production_preference ON production_companies.Production_name = user_production_preference.user_production_name)
      INNER JOIN user_cast_preference ON cast.Cast_Name = user_cast_preference.user_cast_name)
GROUP BY movie_title
ORDER BY total_rating DESC;
```

Comment: Really sorry, I pasted the old SQL Query. This code worked like charm, thanks for help me out.

Comment: This query doesn't get you movies where the user has only actors *or* companies in their preferences, though.

Comment: The idea to combine all cast preferences with all company preferences per movie in order to find the maximum combination is nice. One must keep in mind though, that this leads of course to a big intermediate result. So with huge tables this may no longer be a good approach. For small tables it is.

Comment: Why so @ThorstenKettner ?  We have 200k+ movies our my database. But I will also add one line `where user_id = X`. Why it will not be a good approach?? It will take too long to fetch it?

Comment: @Josh Poor: Let's say there are 100 cast preferences and 100 company preferences per movie (well, if you want the preferences of one user only there would be much less, but if you want to calculate over all users' preferences as in above query it could be even more), then you get 100 x 100 rows per movie for which the sums are built and compared. That's 1 GB rows for this example if I'm not mistaken. So the query can become very slow.